# SQL Server error: the multi-part identifier "C.Name" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL query:

```
CREATE VIEW QueryV5 
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        C.Name, P.Name, SUM(Duration.Time) AS TotalTime
    FROM 
        cmpt354_starwars.dbo.Characters C, 
        cmpt354_starwars.dbo.Planets P, 
        (SELECT (T.[Time of Departure] - T.[Time of Arrival]) AS Time 
         FROM cmpt354_starwars.dbo.TimeTable T 
         WHERE T.CharacterName = C.Name AND T.PlanetName = P.Name) AS Duration
    WHERE 
        P.Affiliation = 'neutral'
```

And I get the errors:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure QueryV5, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "C.Name" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure QueryV5, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "P.Name" could not be bound.

I don't understand what's going on, why it won't let me use Duration as an alias for the nested query. I've compared my query to other people's and I can't see any syntactic differences. What's going on?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C.Name, P.Name` both are having the same column name, that causing the issue. Please provide different alias name for any one of the column will solve the issue.

So this can be

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.Name, P.Name, SUM(Duration.Time) AS TotalTime
```

replace to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.Name, P.Name AS PlantName, SUM(Duration.Time) AS TotalTime
```

---

UPDATE:

Could you try with the JOIN approach

```
CREATE VIEW QueryV5 AS 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    C.Name, P.Name AS PlanetName, SUM(T.[Time of Departure] - T.[Time of Arrival]) AS TotalTime 
FROM cmpt354_starwars.dbo.TimeTable T 
JOIN cmpt354_starwars.dbo.Characters C ON C.Name = T.CharacterName
JOIN cmpt354_starwars.dbo.Planets P ON P.Name = T.PlanetName
WHERE P.Affiliation = 'neutral' 
GROUP BY C.Name, P.Name
```

Comment: That looks like it should work, but I just tried it and the error persists. Exact same error, new query:CREATE VIEW QueryV5 AS
 SELECT DISTINCT C.Name, P.Name AS PlanetName, SUM(Duration.Time) AS TotalTime
  FROM cmpt354_starwars.dbo.Characters C, cmpt354_starwars.dbo.Planets P, (SELECT (T.[Time of Departure] - T.[Time of Arrival]) AS Time FROM cmpt354_starwars.dbo.TimeTable T WHERE T.CharacterName = C.Name AND T.PlanetName = P.Name) AS Duration
   WHERE P.Affiliation = 'neutral'

Comment: Now I get a different error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure QueryV5, Line 8
Column 'cmpt354_starwars.dbo.Characters.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user2469321: add the `GROUP BY C.Name, P.Name` in the last, check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Please, use ANSI syntax of JOIN:

```
CREATE VIEW QueryV5 
AS 

SELECT  T.CharacterName, 
        T.PlanetName, 
        SUM(T.[Time of Departure] - T.[Time of Arrival]) AS TotalTime 
FROM cmpt354_starwars.dbo.TimeTable T 
INNER JOIN cmpt354_starwars.dbo.Planets P
    ON T.PlanetName = P.Name
INNER JOIN cmpt354_starwars.dbo.Characters C
    ON T.CharacterName = C.Name 
WHERE P.Affiliation = 'neutral'
GROUP BY T.CharacterName, T.PlanetName
```

And there is no need for `C.Name` and `P.Name` - use columns from `TimeTable`.